# How can raspberry pi remotely communicate with sensor?

Tags: remote, home-automation

I got my first raspberry kit. And like everyone out there I want to try out home automation. I have a specific question. 
I am setting up the pi as the central server for automation with light bulbs in different rooms as the clients. 
I would like to have sensors attached to the bulbs. And would like to remotely activate the bulbs through raspberry pi. 
What kind of sensor could I use which would be very inexpensive (bluetooth, wifi, infrared or something else?)?

Comment: You might be better off asking on a home automation site.  The Pi is pretty peripheral to the question.

Comment: In addition to being only just related to the Pi, it's unanswerable. What kind of sensor - visible light, infrared, audio, temperature...?

Comment: @goobering I think it is related to the pi in so far as it is explicitly about methodologies that can be integrated with it, as opposed to just any stand-alone system for home automation involving lights.   Anyone asking about this on, e.g., a home automation or general electronics consumer forum is going to get a lot of (proprietary device) suggestions that are cheaper and more practical than anything that will integrate easily with the pi, but then, if you really want it to be something that uses a pi, they aren't applicable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something on a light fixture that can both control and report the state wirelessly, I do not think there are any options that are going to set you back much less than ~$20.  This is because you need something to integrate whatever it is you need to control the light (e.g., a relay), with something that can report the state of the power to the light independently of the state of the relay (I presume this is why you have differentiated between controlling the light and associating a sensor with it), with something that can communicate wirelessly with the pi.

At the high end of the range, I believe there are [XBee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) units that will fit this bill, for which you will also need a corresponding transmitter/reciever on the pi (note, I think XBees are not necessarily both, and since you want two-way communication at both ends, that's what you need, and a transmitter/receiver cost more than just a receiver).  You also need a way to covert the high voltage AC at the fixture to the low voltage DC of the XBee; that is probably another $5-10.  Plus the relay.

You could also use an Arduino nano clone, ~$5, and use 433 Mhz radios, which are similarly cheap for a transmitter / reciever pair (or a wifi module, potentially also very cheap).<sup>1</sup>  Although in theory I think the range on these should be fine inside a house powered from Pis and Arduinos, I have (yet...they are in a drawer...) to try it myself so cannot say for sure; presumably the wifi definitely is.  I think this is one of the cheapest options, but it is also probably one of the more complex to implement and you still need that power supply, so again, another $5 - $10, plus the relay, for a total $15 - $25 per unit.  Probably still less than the XBee solution.  You could use a pi zero much the same way (also $5 -- *not including an SD card*, which an Arduino nano does not require), but these are in high demand and very hard to actually get right now for $5.

Put another way, it is unlikely you are going to be able to do this using DIY tech with a Pi in a manner that cost less than plug n' play, smartphone app controlled things you can buy that screw into light fixtures and install into switch boxes on the wall.  The simple reason here is that there is a growing, already large, market for such products and many manufacturers can easily produce devices dedicated specifically to this at much lower cost than you could create yourself.

This is generally true of any pragmatic pi project (although there are no doubt exceptions) -- e.g., if you just want an indoor home security camera, you are better off buying an integrated unit if your motivation for using the pi is you think you will save a few bucks.  By the time you have all the stuff you actually need, you won't.

However, if you want to do it as a DIY project out of interest, it is not necessarily that much more expensive, discounting the additional time it will take.

---

<sup>1. There are also wifi transceivers with integrated SoC's that may be applicable to this purpose which provide the cheapest option of all, if they can control a relay.  See comments below, and [this example](http://hackaday.com/2015/03/18/how-to-directly-program-an-inexpensive-esp8266-wifi-module/).</sup>

Comment: XBees are awfully expensive-looking when there are [£1 options available](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ESP8266-Serial-Esp-01-WIFI-Wireless-Transceiver-Module-Send-Receive-LWIP-AP-STA-/331887482651?hash=item4d4609171b:g:lXEAAOSw0HVWBL7t) that offer WiFi. The voltage step-down is (or at least should be) fairly worrying, as it's going to get hot and it lives in the ceiling. I wouldn't recommend trying that unless you've done some reasonably serious long term testing and have talked to your home insurance company.

Comment: @goobering Okay, but my understanding of XBees (I could be completely wrong) is they offer a little bit in the way of input/output control such that they could be used here without anything else, whereas a wifi module is in the same category as 433 Mhz radio -- you need at least some kind of additional microcontroller.  You certainly can't just attach it to a relay, etc.   I'll edit in reference to these along with the radios though, forgot about those.

Comment: The ESP8266 is basically a self contained Wi-Fi enabled arduino.

Comment: Ah, dandy.  I'll add that to my own shopping list then ;)  Found a [better description here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678) (guess you have to pay more from a site with better documentation, lol).   I'll make a footnote referring to these comments about that.